# How do you get path to user desktop in XCode?

Tags: ios, cocoa, path, environment-variables

I have tried:

```
path = @"~/Desktop/files/text.plist";
NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

ResultPath: ~/Desktop/files/text.plist

```
path = @"$(HOME)/Desktop/files/text.plist";
NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

ResultPath: $(HOME)/Desktop/files/text.plist

```
path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Desktop/files/text.plist"];
NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

ResultPath: /Users/my_name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/639DC66A-7092-4ECB-9E48-59935AC1C394/Desktop/files/text.plist

1. Is there any way to get to the User's desktop path in XCode?
2. Can environment variables be used in the example above and how?

EDIT: Further explanation on 2nd question:
Just like there are environment variables (or Macros) in the MAC console, can these also be used within the code? If they can be used, can any one help with an example?
like $HOME_DIRECTORY or something like that.

Comment: It looks like you're writing an iOS application. There's no desktop in iOS, so I'm not sure what you're expecting to get here!

Comment: I don't really see how this is related to Xcode at all…

Comment: @duskwuff i am writing an iOS app that's to be run in simulator *only* (yes, there apps like that-think testing environments). As such i need to get the path to the user's Desktop on the Mac.

Comment: @RadekSlupik I'd like to think that the second part of this question concerning using XCode environment variables related to XCode.. yes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can specify the desktop in the search path:

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * desktopPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that it makes no assumptions about how the user has configured his Mac, If his desktop folder isn't in the default location, this will still find the correct one.

Comment: Just FYI, for iOS 8 and Xcode 6, Apple seems to have changed a few things and this yields a path that doesn't exist and isn't the Mac users's desktop: `/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C4BE4D04-304E-44EF-8665-B2DF0AE75EBC/data/Containers/Data/Application/167E7298-E774-4CFF-B252-F61AC60E9027/Desktop`

Comment: @newenglander That's because there is no actual concept of a `Desktop` folder on an iOS device because of the sandboxed file system. The app is running on the simulator, so it is showing the simulator's version of the Desktop. Try running the same code on an actual device, and try putting a file into this "Desktop" folder. Note the error message.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
NSString *pathToDesktop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/Desktop/text.txt", NSUserName()];
```

Comment: This assumes the Desktop folder is located in a particular place. The user can change it, and then this will break.

Comment: @Abizern - You can move the Desktop to another location, but there will always be an alias to it located at /Users/your_name/Desktop, so this method will still work.

Answer (score 1):

I use this statement, it assumes that the Desktop folder is in the usual location.

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"];
```

Comment: For sandboxed app, the `NSHomeDirectory` returns the container path

Answer (score -3):

This should do it for your #1 question:

```
 NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString* documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Can you explain your second question further? :)

Comment: This answer does not seem to work.  It gives me the same path as the third option i have tried above.

Comment: Documents folder ≠ desktop folder